# npm install of Next.js from github fails

Tags: node.js, github, npm, next.js

When trying to npm install zeit/nextjs from Github directly it fails with the following exception.

I get the same error both when running in a docker instance and directly in osx, and both on Node 5.2 and 7.2. First time I'm installing directly from GitHUB, so I don't know if I'm missing something important?

*edit*

```
npm install next
```

works as expected, but does not contain the latest package.json that is needed for Docker

*end edit*

Regards
Mattias

```
root@2cc7a4204924:/usr/src# npm install git+https://github.com/zeit/next.js
.
.
.
.... lots of other packages installing fine .....
.
.
.
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "git+https://github.com/zeit/next.js"
npm ERR! node v7.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! path /usr/src/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall chmod

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/src/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/src/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /usr/src/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why it doesn't work from github but you can do this to install the latest beta from npm:

```
npm i --save next@^2.0.0-beta
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing the package by name installs it just fine but through github it throws errors. It must be a problem with the current version at Github.

```
npm i next          // works
npm i zeit/next.js  // doesn't work
```

Comment: Yes, I should have added that. But I need the version on github, since it fixes my issue with a dependent package https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/344

Comment: Which version of Next are you currently running ? I just installed it and the version is next@1.2.3 . If you have a lower version you could update it.

Comment: Nextjs@1.2.3 does not workin inside docker (or on any Linux host I guess) because of an issue in the version of is-windows-bash that is used (see the references github issue).   A fix for this has been merged into GitHub, so that's why I'm trying to install from github instead of the npm repository.

Comment: Yes, I understood. I just wanted to make sure that you have the latest version.

Comment: I checked the repo and just found your Issue on Github. Hope someone can help.